# CakePHP cookie expiration not working

Tags: cakephp, cookies

Using AppController in CakePHP I set the following cookie settings:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Cookie->name = 'Vinbeo';
    $this->Cookie->time = '7 Days';
}
```

I'm writing two cookies but only the first gets the right expiration time and the other expires when the browser is closed.

I'm using `UsersController` with this model:

```
$this->Cookie->write('name',$name);
```

Comment: Where/How are you writing the other two cookies? AppController?

Comment: I'm writing it in UsersController in this model $this->Cookie->write('name',$name);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->Cookie->write('first_cookie', 'cookie1', false, '7 Days');
$this->Cookie->write('second_cookie', 'cookie2', false, '3 Days');
```

From [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/180/Using-the-Component): The fourth parameter of `write` determines the expiry date. I think when you set properties like the way you are doing it now in the beforeFilter(), it does it only for the one cookie. Need to double check this though.