# cakephp v2.3.7 cookie expire notation issue

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I am using cakePHP v2.3.7,

I have the following issue, I have written in my `app/Config/core.php` file the line

```
'timeout' => 44640, // 31 days.
```

Why is it not possible to put here let's say:  `'1 month'` or `'1 year'` ?

Does it need to be a numeric value only?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because that is just how it works, it's in minutes. Why is it an issue?

Comment: Some people find issues where no one else ever would :) I guess thats just how it works. @Nick: Feel free to provide a PR with a patch that fixes this to work as you want it to.

Comment: @mark I am not trying to find an issue, on the contrary, I am very positive minded and appreciate all the hard work what is done, just wondered if I did something wrong because many and literary many threads here you see that notation of 'x days' Just being a novice doesn't mean I deserve such answers. Only wanted to know/learn about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501086/cakephp-cookie-expiration-not-working?rq=1   this thread for example, just confused, so it seems you can use days but not in the core.php just want clarification on this. The cookbook gives examples as well: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set an string compatible with php `strtotime()` function.

Example: `'+1 Year'`